# Drop a purview collection in microsoft purview

Tags: azure, azure-purview

How can i drop a collection with assest inside ? delete is disabled (screen). thank you[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to delete those assets inside of the collection [before the delete options will be enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/how-to-create-and-manage-collections#delete-a-collection).

Either manually via the UI or programmatically via the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/purview/catalogdataplane/entity/delete-by-guids?tabs=HTTP) or [PyApacheAtlas](https://github.com/wjohnson/pyapacheatlas/blob/master/samples/CRUD/delete_entity.py) delete the eight assets in the collection.

You may have to also delete all of the scans related to the collection as well which can be done via the UI or REST API as well.